# How to sort a value according a typle inside list

Tags: django, django-views, django-queryset

Hello I am getting output like this

```
 [OrderedDict([('id', 113), ('unread', True), ('timestamp', '2019-12-19T08:09:35.042804Z')]),OrderedDict([OrderedDict([('id', 115), ('unread', False), ('timestamp', '2019-10-19T08:09:35.042804Z')]),OrderedDict([OrderedDict([('id', 119), ('unread', True), ('timestamp', '2019-10-19T08:09:35.042804Z')])]
```

What I want to do is I need to filter the datas according to unread= True or unread = False

If I am printing a[0] I can getting

```
OrderedDict([('id', 113), ('unread', True), ('timestamp', '2019-12-19T08:09:35.042804Z')])
```

But I don't know how to get the tuple inside the list and check the values

How can I sort all unreaded messages and readed messages

Comment: You here have an `OrderedDict` that contains `OrderedDict`s as elements?

Comment: Yes..... I am getting response like this

Comment: well it makes things of course much harder of the data is not *flat*. It might be worth first fixing the problem upstream and obtain a "flat" list of `OrderedDict` objects.

Comment: So how to do that?